# Calculating power of a test: Inequality inside normal CDF

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, least-squares, statistical-power

As a part of an econometric exercise I need to calculate the power of a test for a least squares regression. The true value for the parameter is assumed to be $q=0.9$ and the estimated parameter value is $\hat{q}=1.084$ and $se(\hat{q}) = 0.448$.

To get the probability that $q$ lies outside this interval I need to calculate the quantity $P(\frac{\hat{q} - 0.9}{0.448} < - \frac{0.878 - 0.9}{0.448}) + P(\frac{\hat{q} - 0.9}{0.448} > \frac{0.878 - 0.9}{0.448})$ where $\pm 0.878$ comes from 
$q < 0 - 1.96 \times 0.448$ and $q > 0 + 1.96 \times 0.448$.

I don't see how to get from the values in within the brackets above ($P(\cdot)$) to normal CDF as $\Phi(X) + (1 - \Phi(Z))$ which I need to calculate the power of the test. To be more specific, it is the inequality inside of the cdf which I don't know how to handle.

I'm sure this is a trivial thing but unfortunately the econometrics text book from which the exercise is taken does not provide any guidance except for a conceptual definition of the power of a test. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: $\hat q$ has a Student t distribution, not a Normal distribution.  You need to figure out the degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sample size is sufficiently large that you can pretend your t-ratios are normal, then $\frac{\hat{q}-E(q)}{\text{se}(\hat{q})}$ will be a standard normal random variable.

So in the left hand term, let $Z_1=\frac{\hat{q}-E(q)}{\text{se}(\hat{q})}$, simplify the RHS of the inequality to a single number and you will have something of the form $P(Z_1<c)$ for $Z_1$ standard normal. You should be able to convert that to an expression involving $\Phi(_{^\text{something}})$. Repeat the same approach with the next term.